# Easy way to switch between renderers within the same view method

Tags: python, pyramid

I set up my function like this

```
@view_config(
    route_name = 'route_name',
    permissions = 'permissions',
    renderer = 'r.mako'
)
def r( request ):
    # stuff goes here
```

now, I want to add functionality such that I check certain conditions (using ajax) i would use one template, otherwise use another.  is there a way to do this in pyramid?  thanks

Comment: This [blog post](http://cecilphillip.com/content-negotiation-with-the-pyramid-web-framework/) answers your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well you can add the view multiple times with different renderers if you can determine what you want to do via predicates. For example

```
@view_config(route_name='route', xhr=True, renderer='json')
@view_config(route_name='route', renderer='r.mako')
@view_config(route_name='route', request_param='fmt=json', renderer='json')
def r(request):
    # ...
```

Or you can just override the renderer manually via `request.override_renderer = 'b.mako'`:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/renderers.html#overriding-a-renderer-at-runtime

Or you can just explicitly render the response via the `render` and `render_to_response` methods from within the view, as the `renderer` argument is ignored if you return a `Response` object from the view.

Note that the `xhr` predicate in the first example should be sufficient to check for an ajax request. Note also that you don't have to use the same view for both if you don't want to, just depends.

Comment: Also, the `accept` parameter of `view_config` can be used to render the format requested. For example `@view_config(route_name="route", accept="application/json", renderer="json")`.

Comment: `accept` is unreliable unless you add it to all of the views in that "group". It is biased by the quality factor in the accept header, so the other view should `accept='text/html'`, or the json one will always be chosen because if you remember most browsers specify `accept='*/*'`.